# JPA: A question about entityManager.joinTransaction

Tags: java, jpa

Let say we declare a *application-managed* entity manager like following (a similar version can be found at: http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E19798-01/821-1841/bnbqy/index.html):

```
@PersistenceUnit EntityManagerFactory emf;
@Resource UserTransaction utx;
protected void doPost(HttpServletRquest req,...)
   em = emf.createEntityManager();
   try {
     utx.begin(); //(1)
     em.persist(SomeEntity);
     utx.commit();
   } catch (Exception e) {
     utx.rollback();
   }
```

While the code works OK, there are several slides from SUN architects (e.g: http://www.scribd.com/doc/6616366/TS49452007JavaEE) state that the block is **buggy** and "em.joinTransaction()" should be added after line (1) (slide #50).

If exceptions happen, *persistent context* will be *inconsistent* and we simply close the **em**, so What can be potential bug(s) here?

Any suggestions where I'm missing are really appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, the code you're showing is buggy from a JTA perspective.

You need to tell the EM that you want it to be part of a distributed transaction by calling em.joinTransaction(). If you don't call that method, the user transaction and the EM transaction will be disconnected. The javadocs of that method state:

> Indicate to the EntityManager that a JTA transaction is active.

You can also see also that the EM doesn't need to start a transaction when you call em.joinTransaction. If you weren't in a JTA environment, then you would need to call em.getTransaction().begin() and em.getTransaction.commit(), but since you're in a JTA transaction, the UserTransaction is responsible for starting, committing or rolling back.

---

About the second question, there is no problem with the code you have there, as if there's an exception, you're not calling the EM at all. **BUT** if there was an exception, the only method you can (and should) call is em.close(). If you try to do anything else, eg call em.find(), the EM will throw an InvalidStateException.

I hope what I wrote is clear... JTA is a complex monster.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem with the above code is that **sometimes** it doesn't work. While it did work in my trial (I tried with Glassfish/EclipseLink), it may do not work in other cases (e.g.: http://netbeans.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=90031).

One thing I was missing (and was answered by @Augusto) is by using "em.joinTransaction", we not only ask "persistent context" created by em was the same as utx but also register em to utx so that when utx.commit, em will flush it contents to db.

I'm happy with @Augusto answer, but since I cannot login to the account created the question, I could not click the "accept" button; sorry about that.